# How to pass hash object in gRPC ruby client

Tags: ruby, grpc

I want to make a Ruby client.

My proto file looks like:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";
import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";
import "discovery/protobuf/shared/v1beta1/metadata.proto";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option ruby_package = "v1beta1";

message Request {
  ...
  google.protobuf.Struct test = 12;

}
```

In my service_pb.rb file I have:

```
add_message 'request' do
  ...
  optional :test, :message, 12, 'google.protobuf.Struct'
end
```

Now I am trying to pass the request params in my client.rb:

```
params = {xyz: "abc", test: { bar: "296" }}
stub = Message::Stub.new('localhost:9999', :this_channel_is_insecure)
msg = Request.new(params)
```

while running this I am getting: 
`ArgumentError: Unknown field name 'bar' in initialization map entry.`

I need to pass a Hash object in request params.

Comment: I don't know anything about GRPC but am I understanding correctly that your `Request.new(params)` is not working because you haven't registered the `params` keys in the `add_message` block? Maybe it would be easier if you serialize the `params` object to a JSON string

Comment: Making params JSON won't work, it's not rest API.

Comment: Could you please attach your .proto file?

Comment: @GregKrimer I can't update the full proto file we are using it in prod, I can share a snapshot though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to use `Google::Protobuf::Struct.from_hash`
Example code:

```
require 'google/protobuf/well_known_types'
Google::Protobuf::Struct.from_hash({'k' => 123})
=> <Google::Protobuf::Struct: fields: {"k"=><Google::Protobuf::Value: null_value: :NULL_VALUE, number_value: 123.0, string_value: "", bool_value: false, struct_value: nil, list_value: nil>}>
```